# Как добавить список недавних документов в контекстное меню?

Tags: c#, winforms

На скриншоте контекстное меню со списком недавно открытых документов в приложении.
Такое меню открывается при клике правой клавишей по ярлыку приложения в меню пуск.

Пример в Windows 10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добавить список открытых файлов в это меню своего приложения? В Windows Forms.

Comment: А в чём проблема? При каждом открытии файла добавляете его в список. Список выводите в меню. Между запусками программы храните список в настройках.

Comment: Как его "выводить в меню"?

Comment: Если это виндовые "Недавние", то работает только для ассоциированных приложений вроде. Всмысле, если ваше приложение - для открытия какого типа файлов, то оно будет отображать открытые недавно файлы автоматически.

Comment: Ага, понял, что вам нужно. Сейчас напишу.

Comment: Нет, я так и не разобрался пока. Выложу здесь покамест найденные ссылки: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13478089/276994, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103913/How-to-Create-a-Custom-Jumplist-with-Custom-Events, https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Windows-7-Jump-Lists

Comment: И вот ещё: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.jumplist(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Monk, действительно, если ассоциировать файл с приложением, "недавние документы" отображаются в контекстном меню. Спасибо!

Comment: @VladD, я может ошибаюсь, но JumpList только для константных ссылок легко строится.

Comment: @Monk: Там ещё есть JumpTask, с ним можно что угодно творить.